# How to associate metadata with many different types of controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, reactiveui

I have a bunch of controls that may or may not be enabled based on errors in other controls.  When a control is disabled, I want to give the user an explanation of why it is currently disabled.  However, I am already using ToolTip for help text.  So I thought I would make error messages appear in a static text box when the user mouses over a grayed-out component.

Simplified xaml:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 10">
    <TextBox x:Name="thtkDirTextBox" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tououDatTextBox" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="touhouExeSelector" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="stageSelector" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="sceneSelector" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"/>
    <GroupBox Header="Errors">
        <TextBox IsEnabled="False" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" FontSize="10" Height="50">
            Mouse over an item that's grayed out and the reason why will appear here.
        </TextBox>
    </GroupBox>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Content="Save as..." ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"></Button>
        <Button Content="Quick Play" ToolTip="yadda yadda help text"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Crucially, in order for this to work, each component will need to be associated with a custom piece of metadata to hold its error message.  (Different controls may have different reasons for being grayed out!)

I read about DependencyProperties, but it seems that using them requires one to subclass a control.  If I have to make subclasses of `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, and `Button`, then I'll end up with duplicated code across three different incompatible DependencyProperties.  (also, virtually all examples of them involve the use of Triggers, which I don't think can help me here?)

I see there is also a `Tag` property.  Is this a fair usage of the property?  What if I later find that I need another Tag property?  Should I just assume that this probably won't happen?  (Or maybe if it does ultimately come to that, perhaps it is not unreasonable to e.g. serialize JSON objects into Tag in order to store multiple attributes?)

What should I do here?

---

**Additional details:**

I am using ReactiveUI to propagate information from one control to another.  For each control that can be grayed out, the ViewModel ultimately constructs an `IObservable` whose items are either some value needed by the control (e.g. an `IEnumerable<string>` with choices for a ComboBox, or perhaps just a `Unit` as a proof of validity for a button), or an error message.

Given one of these observables, I can easily `OneWayBind` a `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` of type `bool` to the control's `IsEnabled` property, and hope to do something similar for the error message.  If I were to use ToolTips for this, it would be fairly simply:

```
// ViewModel
this.stageSelectorErrorMessage =
    this.stageSelectorEithers
    .Select(either => either.Error) // string on failure, null on success
    .ScheduleOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .ToProperty(this, x => x.StageSelectorErrorMessage);

// View
this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration => {
    // ...
    this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel,
        viewModel => viewModel.StageSelectorErrorMessage,
        view => view.stageSelector.ToolTip
    ).DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
})
```

I haven't yet decided how to hook up the mouseover events. (haven't gotten that far)

Comment: you can use an attached Dependency Property. it can be applied to any control without creating subclasses

Comment: _"What should I do here?"_ -- far too broad a question. That said: `Tag` is there for you to use, if you find it useful. If you need it for multiple things, store a user-defined type with the multiple things. That said, there's so little detail in your question, there could be any number of legitimate ways to approach the solution. You haven't explained, for example, what mechanism is actually being used to disable controls based on errors. Nor how errors are propagated. Nor how you'd have used tooltips, had that been an option (i.e. if you weren't already using them for something else).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added additional details explaining how I am using ReactiveUI to take errors that occur in one control, and propagate them to all of the other controls that depend on them, as well as how I would have used ToolTips

Comment: Are all of your controls in your view bounded to a property in the viewmodel?

Comment: Each control has several of its properties bound to properties of the ViewModel. (one for IsEnabled, one for ItemsSource or Text, and as of late one for Tag as I experiment with this).  All of the properties on the viewmodel for any one control come from very closely related IObservable streams (I just do different things to the stream of Eithers).

Comment: Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-validation-logic-on-custom-objects  With this interface you can validate properties in your viewmodel.

Comment: Are these effectively validation.errors? Because there's already validation mechanisms you could use.

Comment: They don't seem like validation errors to me, because they all have to do with how one component affects another.  Example:  If no selection is chosen from touhouExeSelector, then the "Quick Play" button will be unavailable (but everything else, including "Save As", remains available).  Another example: Some checkboxes may become unavailable depending on the stage the user selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see there is also a `Tag` property. Is this a fair usage of the property?

A better approach would be to create a strongly typed [attached dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) that you can set on any element. Just define a static class where you register the property:

```
public static class Metadata
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InfoProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "Info",
          typeof(string),
          typeof(Metadata),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetInfo(UIElement element, string value) => element.SetValue(InfoProperty, value);

    public static string GetInfo(UIElement element) => (string)element.GetValue(InfoProperty);
}
```

You can set it on any `UIElement` like this:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="False" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200" FontSize="10" Height="50"
             local:Metadata.Info="Mouse over an item that's grayed out and the reason why will appear here.">
</TextBox>
```

You get the value programmatically using the `GetInfo` method:

```
string info = Metadata.GetInfo(theControl);
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I tried that at some point but couldn't figure out how to set values. It somehow didn't occur to me to that I could use GetInfo/SetInfo directly... (I assumed they were only meant to be used by the framework.)